# How to use $.extend in vanilla js?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have been using jQuery for a long time, so while coding in `Vanilla JS` I am kind of wondering about how can we use something similar to `$`. extend in vanilla JS.

Answer (score 17):

There are basically these three approaches -

1. Easiest way is to use Object.assign() function

Syntax - Object.assign(target, ...sources)

So you can code in following way -

```
var obj1 = { a: 1, c:4 };
var obj2 = { a: 2, b:3 };
var copy = Object.assign(obj1, obj2);
console.log(copy); // { a: 2, c: 4, b: 3 }
```

Even deep cloning is possible refer [Mozilla Doc.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)

2. Otherwise if you want to use extend in code. One describe extend as below - 
   Taken from this post [Vanilla JavaScript version of jQuery.extend()](https://gomakethings.com/vanilla-javascript-version-of-jquery-extend/)

   ```
   /* Pass in the objects to merge as arguments.
      For a deep extend, set the first argument to `true`.*/


   var extend = function () {

   // Variables
   var extended = {};
   var deep = false;
   var i = 0;
   var length = arguments.length;

   // Check if a deep merge
   if ( Object.prototype.toString.call( arguments[0] ) === '[object Boolean]' ) {
       deep = arguments[0];
       i++;
   }

   // Merge the object into the extended object
   var merge = function (obj) {
       for ( var prop in obj ) {
           if ( Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call( obj, prop ) ) {
               // If deep merge and property is an object, merge properties
               if ( deep && Object.prototype.toString.call(obj[prop]) === '[object Object]' ) {
                   extended[prop] = extend( true, extended[prop], obj[prop] );
               } else {
                   extended[prop] = obj[prop];
               }
           }
       }
   };

   // Loop through each object and conduct a merge
   for ( ; i < length; i++ ) {
       var obj = arguments[i];
       merge(obj);
    }
          return extended;
   };
   ```

With this definition in code extend() function can be used for extending objects as mentioned below -

```
var newObjectShallow = extend(object1, object2, object3);
```

3. If object is simple (no deep cloning needed) following approach can be used  - more details are mentioned [here](https://gist.github.com/cferdinandi/4f8a0e17921c5b46e6c4'%3Ehere%3C/a%3E%20as%20extend.js)

   ```
   var extend = function ( defaults, options ) {
   var extended = {};
   var prop;
   for (prop in defaults) {
       if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(defaults, prop)) {
           extended[prop] = defaults[prop];
       }
   }
   for (prop in options) {
       if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(options, prop)) {
           extended[prop] = options[prop];
       }
   }
   return extended;
   };
   ```

Hope this helps anybody searching for $.extend implementation in native js

Comment: It's fine to post a question and answer it, but the substance of the answer should be posted **here** (with appropriate attribution and a link if you want). Otherwise, your answer only remains useful as long as those links continue to work.

Comment: Also, you might want to mention [`Object.assign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)

Comment: Thanks I have modified my answer.

Comment: poorly styled code. it's hard to read it that way

Comment: #2 literally doesn't work in the context I'm using it, got a STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION